# Why is my Firefox OS 1.3 phone not showing in App Dev Manager?

Tags: firefox-os

I am trying to use a FireFox OS device that runs OS 1.3 on my app dev. I have went through the instructions and still there is no device name that i can test an app with. Are there windows drivers that have to be installed. It seems like everything was installed but there is no device name. I am not sure if I gave my phone an actual name on the setup menu but I would think there would be a default menu. The only thing is that I have not installed a simCard because I do not need the phone I just want to test my apps before they go up on the Firefox OS marketplace.

Note 1: When I plug in the phone it causes firefox OS to flip back and forth between the browser and the develop manager that opens when the web tools kit is opened.

[image]

Instructions that I found for the phone that I have ZTE OPEN FireFox OS

```
Power off your phone, remove the battery to access the microSD card and extract the card from its holder.
Connect the microSD card to your desktop machine.
Move US_DEV_FFOS_V1.1.0B04_UNFUS_SD.zip or EU_DEV_FFOS_V1.1.0B04_UNFUS_SD.zip (depending on the version you downloaded) to the root directory of your microSD card. Do NOT unzip the file.
Disconnect the microSD card from your desktop computer and return it to your phone.
Hold the volume up button and power key down simultaneously. Volume up is activated by pressing the upper part of the long key on the left side of the phone. If you did it properly, you’ll enter the Firefox OS recovery mode. (Note: the Firefox OS logo may display briefly before you enter the recovery mode; sometimes this can take a little while.)
Use the volume up/down key to move from one item to the other in the menu, and choose “apply update from external storage.”
Press the power key to confirm the selection. You’ll see a new screen listing the files you have on the microSD card.
Again use volume up/down key to select the firmware: either US_DEV_FFOS_V1.1.0B04_UNFUS_SD.zip or EU_DEV_FFOS_V1.1.0B04_UNFUS_SD.zip (depending on the version you downloaded), and press the power key to confirm.
If everything went well, you’ll see a sequence of status messages, culminating with one that says, “Install from sdcard complete.”. You’ll need to select “reboot system now” after the installation has completed. Your phone will then reboot, and you’ll see the configuration screen you saw the first time you powered on the phone.
```

Comment: You need a windows driver.  Which phone do you have?  If you have the flame see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/Flame  The driver is available under pushing apps to your Flame

Comment: 4.0" ZTE OPEN C Latest Firefox OS 3G dual core Unlocked S... (331304334479) the number is the ebay auction number. This is the phone that I purchased. http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyEbayBeta&CurrentPage=MyeBayNextSummary this is the link. Does the phone have the drivers on them (or some of them)?

Comment: I believe the usb driver is in the software download on the ZTE support site.  Take a look at the Upgrading Firefox OS section of this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developer_phone_guide/ZTE_OPEN_C